# What's difference between imported svg, say from mui-icons and as a file, and is there a solution such as React.createElement?

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js

Question may seem stupid, but it isn't at least for me

When I import mui icons - I can use them as ReactComponent eg. `<ImportedIcon />`. When this happens I can apply styles such as active class and it works as expected

However, when I import svg from file, I can't use it as ReactComponent and see error such as

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

So, in looping I distinguish them by src property, and if it exists I call Image component of next.js and it works fine, but ... svg is imported through img's src property. I can't apply styles related to svg anymore

Looked at @svgr/webpack, but it kills interface (other built in svgs) which is not case to see in.

Tried to play with React.createElement, but without success

Any help appreciated